# Watson Alchemy - How to Understand Sentiment Ratings

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

Watson Alchemy returns "sentiment ratings" of ".85 anger" for example, but I cannot understand ON WHAT SCALE...  Is that 85%  - (I don't think so).  Does anyone have information on how to read the data?  Thanks!

Comment: If the answer correctly answers your question, consider to accept it by clicking the tick sign under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means 85%. Here is the API reference [link](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#emotion_analysis). Scroll a bit down to the response section of Emotion Analysis request and you'll see the docs.

> docEmotions - Object containing emotion keys and score values (0.0 to
>   1.0). If a score is above 0.5, then the text can be classified as conveying the corresponding emotion.

An example:

```
"docEmotions": {
    "anger": "0.639028",
    "disgust": "0.009711",
    "fear": "0.037295",
    "joy": "4e-05",
    "sadness": "0.002552"
  }
```